# Jenkins will not use Java 7 compiler

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm working with a team on a maven project, and I set up a build job for it in Jenkins.

Recently, someone on the team added code that switches on a String.  This caused the build to fail in Jenkins with the following error:

```
error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
```

So of course I realized Jenkins needs to be using Java 7, not Java 5.

First, I remoted into the server, opened a cmd, and did `where java` and `java -version`.  I checked my environment variables and my path.  Everything is pointing to the same Java 7 jdk directory: `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`.

Then I checked Jenkins to see if it was configured to use the correct JDK.  It is:
 [image: Jenkins JDK]

In fact, that's the only Java that the Jenkins server is set up to use, and it's the only Java installed in the Server.

As a last resort, I installed the JDK parameter plugin into Jenkins.  I then set the project to use the Java 7 parameter:

[image: Parameter JDK]

But still, I get the same error.

Am I missing something?  What could be causing this?  Most importantly, how can I solve it and get Jenkins to use `-source 1.7` instead of `-source 1.5`?

Comment: And does mvn compile do the job?

Comment: What about your pom.xml if you are using Maven? What JVM does it specify? That could be where the `source 1.5` is coming from.

Comment: These are the JDK configurations for Jenkins. You should also check you `pom` for [similar settings](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: Ohh... *face-palm*  it doesn't.  That's the problem.  Duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your pom.xml and what java version (for the source) is specified there. That could be where the `source 1.5` is coming from.

```
<properties>
   <jee.level>1.4</jee.level>
   <jdk.level>1.5</jdk.level>
</properties>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <source>${jdk.level}</source>
       <target>${jdk.level}</target>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It doesn't specify... which I guess is the problem.  I'm sure adding the maven-compiler-plugin and specifying source and target as `1.7` will fix it.  I wonder why it defaulted to `1.5` though.  Any insight there?

Comment: Please be sure and let us know if the `maven-compiler-plugin` with project properties (see above) fixes it.

Comment: It fixed it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  (I actually feel kinda silly because I've done this before -- just forgot to consider the pom.)