# Jenkins maven release plugin with different jdk

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I want to perform a maven release that compile java 1.8 code on a Jenkins install that runs on jdk 1.7

I have a project that I compile with java 1.8 using the  [JDK Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JDK+Parameter+Plugin) . It works when doing a regular build.

When I do a maven release using the maven release plugin, it forks a JVM with java 1.7 instead of the version specified on the plugin. I guess that it takes the java version in the environment.

If I set JAVA_HOME for that job to 1.8 it works.

I am trying to find a solution where I don't have to override the JAVA_HOME in all my jobs.

I tried to use the solution from a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157231/jenkins-will-not-use-java-7-compiler) which fixed OP problem by forcing a compiler version:

```
<properties>
   <jee.level>1.8</jee.level>
   <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
</properties>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <source>${jee.level}</source>
       <target>${jdk.level}</target>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but I end up with:

```
 [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project redeem-commons-test: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to upgrage the JDK of the container in which jenkins runs and add a JAVA_OPTS to the latter to support the previous JDK version. e.g. `-Djava.version=1.7`

This way I can build and maven release projects that are java 7 or java 8.

Answer (score 0):

A similar, but slightly different approach is to let Jenkins to have the current JVM, and install an alternate JVM on the Jenkins' machine on a specific folder.

Then on your project, you can define the JVM machine as a pre-step called `Inject environment variables` and set on `Properties Content`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
```

The advantage is that you do not need to modify all the old existing projects are using the previous JVM, and only on this project you are selecting a different JVM.

Note that this approach is due to, despite Jenkins allowing to use multiples JDKs, they are working fine for a standard `mvn clean install` but is failing when using the "Mvn Release Plugin" as requested by the OP.